# Tray Icon load split position every time reboot

Tags: windows-7-x64

Is there a way to sort order icons?
Sometime they didn't show correctly.

I tried to remove some icons from start menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drag any icon to any where as you desird. These will remember the position.